# What is $R(k,l)$?

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I'm reading Landman/Robertson's: *Ramsey Theory on the Integers*. It states the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1.15** (Ramsey's Theorem for Two Colors). Let $k,l \geq 2$. There exists a least positive integer $R=R(k,l)$ such that every edge-coloring of $K_R$, with the colors red and blue, admits either a red $K_k$ subgraph or a blue $K_l$ subgraph.

But It's not clear what $R(k,l)$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're actually *defining* $R(k, l)$ in the statement of that theorem. It would probably have been more evident if they said something like:

**Theorem 1.15**: Let $k,l\geq 2$. There exists a least positive integer $R$ such that every edge-coloring of $K_R$, with the colors red and blue, admits either a red $K_k$ subgraph or a blue $K_l$ subgraph.

**Note**: The integer $R$ guaranteed by Theorem 1.15 is denoted $R(k, l)$.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks.